# Number of ways to re-arrange INTERNATIONAL with L to the right of E.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

How many ways can you re-arrange

> I N T E R N A T I O N A L

such that **L** is always to the right of **E**, it does not need to be a specific number of places, so both

> **E** **L** I N T R N A T I O N A

and

> I N T E R N **L** A T I O N **A**

are valid combinations.

I think you could do it by fixing **E** in the first place, seeing the number of arrangements, then **E** in the second place. But I can't get that method to work and I was hoping for a more elegant approach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Exactly half of all possible arrangements have L to the right of E.

Comment: Thank you! Is there any way I could see/prove that?

Comment: @ChickenP: Just think about it for a while. You should be able to work it out for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use symmetry, you can

1) choose the two places for the E and the L, which can be done in $\dbinom{13}{2}$ ways

2) arrange the other 11 letters in the remaining places, which can be done in $\displaystyle\frac{11!}{3!2!2!2!}$ ways.

Therefore there are $\displaystyle\binom{13}{2}\frac{11!}{3!2!2!2!}$ such arrangements.

Comment: This makes sense as well, thank you!